# Can you make web page act like a single pixel image?

Tags: php, html, image

I'm building a tracking feature for the first time.

Mistakenly I had first attempted to create a PHP script which could handle the tracking criteria, but I fail to understand if it's possible to make it appear inside an email.
[That's what I get for not planning this feature]

I'm going to go ahead and add a single pixel to the the emails now, and use the server access log to increemnt the tracking stats.

It got me thinking though, is there anyway to spoof a webpage into acting like a single pixel? And would it work on an email?

Sounds all too far fetched but would love for someone to clarify why it wouldn't be the case if not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A PHP script can act like any kind of document you'd like it to, you just need to let the browser (or email client, etc) know what's happening.

By default, PHP will send back a `Content-Type` header of *text/html*, which says that you're serving a webpage. But you can override this to send whatever you'd like - if you want your script to generate a PDF, or an Excel sheet, or an image, you just need to send the right header. To do this, you just need to make a call to the [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, specifying the relevant content type. For an image, this would be something like:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

After that, if you echo out the source of an image, the client will treat it like one. If you've got a single-pixel image flle in the same directory as the PHP script, this can be as simple as:

```
readfile('single_pixel_image.png');
```

which reads the file directly off the disk and sends it to the client.

The important part of all this is that before you make the call to `header`, you can do whatever you like. Log things in a database, write files to disk, post information to an API, anything you would do in a normal PHP script.

After you've written everything you need, you can just embed it using a normal image tag:

```
<img src="tracking.php" />
```

One thing you might want to do on top of this is to redirect a more "standard" looking image filename to your script, and add a unique identifier. In Apache, you'd do something like this, but depending which webserver you're using, you'll need to make adjustments:

```
RewriteRule ^/?tracking/(.*).png$ tracking.php?track=$1 [QSA, L]
```

This would let you use `tracking/1234.png` in your email image tag, and behind the scenes your PHP will run. In the script, you can use `$_GET['track']` to refer to your unique ID, and log whatever needs logging.

Comment: Just to add note. Not every mail program opens external images in emails. For example Thunderbird asks user first if he/she wants to open external images in this email, so it won't be 100% accurate. I think it's better to "Request a read receipt" in your emails.